# Create Class Specific RuboCop Cop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

We have a library that we use internally that requires you to return a specific type from the method you define. I'm trying to write a cop that enables us to detect that case. Here is the situation I want to detect and flag:

1. You are inside the `Slayer::Command` class
2. You've returned something other than a call to `pass` or `flunk!`

It doesn't seem like there's an easy way to check *both* the call and the parent class, but I know it's doable, because the `Rails/HasAndBelongsToMany` cop only triggers inside Rails models, not Rails controllers. More specifically, there definitely isn't an easy way to iterate all returns, because the number 1 cause of this bug is people forgetting that the last branch of a method is the return balue.

What I have so far is this:

```rb
require 'rubocop'

module Slayer
  class CommandReturn < RuboCop::Cop::Base
    def_node_search :explicit_returns, 'return'
    def_node_matcher :slayer_command?, "(class (const (const nil :Slayer) :Command) _)"
    def_node_matcher :is_call_to_pass?, "(send nil :pass ?)"
    def_node_matcher :is_call_to_flunk?, "(send nil :flunk! ?)"

    def on_def(node)
      return unless node.method?(:call)
      return unless in_slayer_command?(node)

      explicit_returns(node) do |node|
        validate_return! node.child_nodes.first, node
      end

      return # Temporarily does not look at implicit returns
      implicit_returns(node) do |node|
        validate_return! node
      end
    end

    private

    # Continue traversing `node` until you get to the last expression.
    # If that expression is a call to `.can_see?`, then add an offense.
    def implicit_returns(node)
      raise "Not Implemented Yet"
    end

    def in_slayer_command?(node)
      node.ancestors.any? &:slayer_command?
    end

    def validate_return!(node, return_node = nil)
      return if is_call_to_pass? node
      return if is_call_to_flunk? node

      add_offense(return_node || node, message: "call in Slayer::Command must return the result of `pass` or call `flunk!`")
    end
  end
end
```

I need help with two things:

1. Is this really the best way to check the class' parent? What about inheriting from something else that inherits from Slayer::Command? Something feels off here.
2. What's the best way to implement the `implicit_returns` method? That feels like it should be baked in and I'm just missing it.

Comment: This isn't really something that you would do with Rubucop. Rubucop is for enforcing code quality issues by analyzing the source code - it won't actually verify the returns of your methods. For that you want something like Sorbet.

Comment: I have no problem if this misses some edge cases or if it doesn't catch issues like people overriding methods they shouldn't. All I want is to catch `return x` where x is _not_ `(send :pass ...)` or `(send :flunk! ...)`. And to include implicit returns. It's a _textual_ match, which felt like a good fit. Adding Sorbet is a non-starter. The CI pipeline for this client is already painfully slow.

Comment: OK, it looks like 'manually' is the way to go for checking if you're in a particular class for a given cop: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rails/blob/e4b9942d80f4fcc9f68c868cdc26453c0bfebc20/lib/rubocop/cop/mixin/active_record_helper.rb#L6